# How I can modify the content of the pointer of a char with the value expressed as an int in ascii?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to define a simple function in c to encrypt a text, I'm very struggled. this is the question, look the function:

```
string[i] = (string[i] * hash)/4;
```

why the value of the `string[i]` inside the parenthesis is treated as `(int)ascii` but the value modified in `string[i]` before "=" is the memory pointer ?
Consider that the value of string inside a function `crypt (char *string, int hash)` is referred to a struct `account.passwd`.
I'm also tried with this:

```
*(string+i) = (string[i] * hash)/4;
```

but same result.
How I can modify the content of the pointer of a char with the value expressed as an int in ascii ?

Function:

```
void crypt (char string[50], int hash){
    int i = 0;
    while (string[i] != 0){
     string[i] = (string[i] * hash)/4;      
     printf ("string %d\n", string[i]);
     i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Would you consider using formattion?

Comment: You *are* modifying the content of the string

Comment: `string[i]` is the value not the pointer why do you think otherwise

Comment: Try `string[i] = (unsigned char)((string[i] * hash)/4;)`

Comment: `string[i]` and `*(string+i)` are absolutely same. First one is short hand notation and second being actual notation (referring a pointer with incremented memory places)

Comment: yes it works but sincerely don't understood why, sorry but I'm very new in dev world and this place is amazing

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
printf("string %d\n", string[i]);
```

prints the character at `i`, which is a small integer (that's what `char` means), as an integer using `%d`. If you want to see the resulting character, you need to print it as such:

```
printf("string '%c'\n", string[i]);
```

Here I use `%c`, which formats as the character. I added single quotes to make it clearer to the user that single characters are printed, those are just ornamental.

Note that your algorithm is "dangerous", since it's easy to have integer overflow when scaling a `char` by an `int`.

Comment: yes I know, but when I print the value in %d I receive the int stored in memory position pointed in the string[i] after the function is executed, I mean when execute  string[i] = (string[i] * hash)/4; the value modified is the address of string[i] not the content.

Comment: @QuirinoDina No, the value modified is never the address. I don't even understand what you mean, an array like `string` is a sequence of memory locations, and you seem to think that you should be able to change the address of individual elements? That would make it no longer be an array, and is simply not possible. You can't have an array without having elements at sequential addresses.

Comment: you were right, I realized now that I'm storing a number "long" on a char variable and the result has been truncated from the first 8bit. thanks for the support !